# Fiddler Blocking img/only allowing certain URLs

Tags: block, fiddler

I'd like to use fiddler to block a whole bunch of img URL's, and also enable the reset of them, and only allow a specific few of these img URL's.

Is it possible to make a rule for everything under a certain .image title and make anything with that name reset, EXCEPT a specified few?

I have too many urls to add to the autoresponder one by one, and also it doesn't seem to work with .img url's. Sorry if this isn't clear, I'm a complete novice. I've tried researching myself but no luck.